# Most efficient way to store massive amounts of records into a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array of mysql uids being returned and stored into an array in PHP, however, being that there are over 100,000 records, it is taking a very long time to do this. I'm just wondering if there's a faster and more efficient way to store a massive amount of records into an array. Your input is appreciated!

Comment: First thing to ask: Do you actually NEED all those records? Filtering only the necessary ones could save you a lot of time without changing a lot of code.

Comment: If you know how many uids there are in advance, then use SPLFixedArray for better memory usage

Comment: Unfortunately, yes I need all of the uids stored in the array. And my work deals with php, so I'm unable to switch to another language. I looked at SPLFixedArray and it seems like a good idea. My question about that is if I had uids between 1 - 100,000, would I need to constantly change the array length or would I be able to set it to the max int size that's in the table and it would store everything?

Comment: @Akshay2598 I didn't know about `SPLFixedArray`, which meets OP's requirements. I deleted my advice.

Comment: Once you've instantiated an SPLFixedArray, avoid changing its size if at all possible as that is a big performance overhead: SPLFixedArray is significantly more memory efficient, and slightly faster than a standard PHP array, but at a cost in flexibility

Comment: Depending on your used DB Connector, the fetch process there could be a major source of perfomance issues too. The standard array combined with the mysqli_fetch_array functions should actually be quiet fast. (ex: zend_db_row is VERY slow here)

Comment: If you're populating this array from a database; then you should be able to get the count of records returned by the query before instantiating your SPLFixedArray, so you shouldn't need to change its size

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll look into SPLFixedArray